# 2D Boolean Array Vertical, Horizontal, and Diagonal Assignment

Tags: java, arrays

Honestly I'm probably overthinking this, but if you have a `boolean[8][8]` array and a value of true within that, how would you make all horizontal, vertical, and diagonal values true as well?

For example, given the [X], how do I make all of the other values X as well:

```
0 0 X 0 0  X  0 0
0 0 0 X 0  X  0 X
0 0 0 0 X  X  X 0
X X X X X [X] X X
0 0 0 0 X  X  X 0
0 0 0 X 0  X  0 X
0 0 X 0 0  X  0 0
0 X 0 0 0  X  0 0
```

Right now I am able to do the vertical and horizontal:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++){
        if (boolean[i][l]){
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
                boolean[i][k] = true;
                boolean[k][l] = true;}
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in your loop, you need a break away variable once you find the first true value. I'd suggest a boolean isFound as one of the conditions in your for loop. Aside from that, here is how I'd go about it (NOTE: This would be placed right below the vertical/horizontal in your loop):

```
//positive slope diagonal
if(((i - Math.min(i, l)) + k) < 8 && ((l - Math.min(i, l)) + k) < 8)
    testArray[(i - Math.min(i, l)) + k][(l - Math.min(i, l)) + k] = true;

//negative slope diagonal
if((k) < 8 && ((l + i) - k) >= 0 && ((l + i) - k) < 8)
    testArray[k][(l + i) - k] = true;
```

In this example, the two diagonals are split up. For the first diagonal, I check to make sure its position is within the bounds of the array (I'll explain how i determine the position in a bit.) Secondly, I determine the starting position's X and Y value of each diagonal, located in the parentheses. Lastly, I find the positions by moving K units in the X and Y direction (step by step) from the starting position to traverse the grid with the diagonal. The same is repeated for the diagnose pointing the other way, but the X value has K subtracted, not added, as as the diagonal points to the opposite direction. Exact logic for the starting position and movement can be best found by toying with the location or drawing my algorithm out.

Eg. [image]

Placement (Note that I added in variable to make sure to stop after finding the one true value):

```
    boolean notFound = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8 && notFound; i++){
        for (int l = 0; l < 8 && notFound; l++){
            if (testArray[i][l]){
                for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
                    testArray[i][k] = true;
                    testArray[k][l] = true;

                    if(((i - Math.min(i, l)) + k) < 8 && ((l - Math.min(i, l)) + k) < 8)
                        testArray[(i - Math.min(i, l)) + k][(l - Math.min(i, l)) + k] = true;

                    if((k) < 8 && ((l + i) - k) >= 0 && ((l + i) - k) < 8)
                        testArray[k][(l + i) - k] = true;       
                }
                notFound = false;
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Where exactly would the code get placed. Is it inside the 3rd loop or inside the if statement in the 2nd loop? Because this code does NOT work if it's inside the 3rd loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full working example that solves this problem. See comments in the code for more details:

```
public class Boolean_Array
{
    private static final int SIZE = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create the boolean array
        boolean [][] boolArr = new boolean [SIZE][SIZE];

        // 1. Set the row, col of the true
        int row = 3;
        int col = 5;

        // 2. Make the vertical, horizontal and diagonals true
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            // Do the vertical and horizontal
            boolArr[row][i] = true;
            boolArr[i][col] = true;

            // Do the diagonals
            setDiagonol(boolArr, row - i, col - i, i); // up and to the left
            setDiagonol(boolArr, row - i, col + i, i); // up and to the right
            setDiagonol(boolArr, row + i, col - i, i); // down and to the left
            setDiagonol(boolArr, row + i, col + i, i); // down and to the right
        }

        print(boolArr);
    }

    private static void setDiagonol (boolean [][] boolArr, int row, int col, int i)
    {
        try
        {
            boolArr[row][col] = true;
        }
        catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe)
        {
            // catching for convenience so we don't have to check the bounds
        }
    }

    private static void print (boolean [][] boolArr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(boolArr[i][j] == true ? "X " : "0 ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
0 X 0 0 0 X 0 0 
0 0 X 0 0 X 0 0 
0 0 0 X 0 X 0 X 
0 0 0 0 X X X 0 
X X X X X X X X 
0 0 0 0 X X X 0 
0 0 0 X 0 X 0 X 
0 0 X 0 0 X 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printGrid(3, 2);
    System.out.println();

    printGrid(5, 4);
    System.out.println();

    printGrid(7, 0);
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printGrid(int x, int y) {
    boolean[][] grid = new boolean[8][8];

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < grid[0].length; l++) {

            // horizontal and vertical
            if (x == i || y == l) {
                grid[i][l] = true;
            }

            // diagonals
            if (Math.abs(x - i) == Math.abs(y - l)) {
                grid[i][l] = true;
            }

            System.out.print(String.format("%-2s", grid[i][l] == true ? "X" : "O"));
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output

```
X O X O X O O O 
O X X X O O O O 
X X X X X X X X 
O X X X O O O O 
X O X O X O O O 
O O X O O X O O 
O O X O O O X O 

O O O O X O O O 
X O O O X O O O 
O X O O X O O X 
O O X O X O X O 
O O O X X X O O 
X X X X X X X X 
O O O X X X O O 
O O X O X O X O 

X O O O O O O X 
X O O O O O X O 
X O O O O X O O 
X O O O X O O O 
X O O X O O O O 
X O X O O O O O 
X X O O O O O O 
X X X X X X X X
```